# Google Analytics Universal changing client ID on each page load

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a Wordpress site loading Google Analytics Universal through GTM. I was brought in to help set up better conversion tracking on their online booking system that loads from a different domain in an iFrame. I set up a solution using [Simo Shave's blog post](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cookieless-tracking-cross-site-iframes/).
When debugging that, I noticed that this site will change the client ID value on each page load.

To debug, I set up a new workspace in GTM, then paused every single tag, and set up a brand new Google Analytics Universal tag, using the build in "all pages" trigger, then started testing using Tag Assistant. I can see that the only tag firing is the new GA tag, but I'm still seeing the exact same problem:
Using the GA Debug plugin, or just checking the google-analytics.com/collect?v1= tag in the Network tab, I see that every page on this site loads a new "cid" value. Even reloading the same page will result in a different CID value. Unfortunately, this is wrecking my ability to track page-to-page behavior and attribute orders to landing pages, etc....

any idea what would cause Google Analytics (or GTM?) to generate a new client ID on each page load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depend on consent mode e CMP user (i.e. Cookiebot that is integrated with GTM). If statistic cookies are denied, the `clientId` will change on each pageview for privacy reason.

Check the dataLayer, if `analytics_storage` is `denied` the `clientId` will change.

Comment: Interesting - I'm not familiar with that. This is a USA website, and currently does not have any cookie consent management platform enabled, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: sorry - I'm still struggling a bit. I'm reviewing the data layer in dev tools console, but I'm not able to fid any reference to `analytics_storage` - is there a specific node I should look for and a better way for me to find that?

Comment: You can read more info about consent here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/consent-settings-google-tag-manager/